# Double screen problem in 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop and a big Dell screen, I want to use Dell screen together with my laptop screen so that I have dual screen.

The default setting in Ubuntu 16.04LTS is that my laptop screen is on the left while the big Dell screen is on the right. I want to change this so that the big Dell screen is on the left while my laptop in on the right.

I set this through Settings->Display, after setting, it works as expected for about 1~2 minutes, and suddenly the system returns to default, that is the laptop screen left while big Dell screen right.

Why does the system always returns default setting without my content? how can I do the setting persistently as I expect?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm reading this correctly, you're opening the display settings as shown in the image above. You then click on and drag one of the displays to the opposite side of the other display. You click the Apply button and your changes are maintained momentarily before they switch back to the way they were.

After clicking the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button, you must also confirm that they display settings look correct
[image: Screenshot_from_2017-04-25_14-38-03.png]
If you don't click the <kbd>Keep This Configuration</kbd> button before the countdown reaches zero, your display will revert back to the previous settings. This protects you in the event that you make a change which leaves your displays in a dysfunctional state.

Comment: I don't see the popup window you put here, and even the "System Settings" window simply doesn't pop up after I do the screen switching.

Comment: If you're not seeing this window, then that's where you're problem is coming in. You need to find this windows (maybe it opens behind something else?) and select the option to keep the configuration or it will continue to simply revert back to the previous settings.